# MS Word 2010 Completely reformatted my whole document

Tags: templates, docx, word-2010, reformatting

I'm thinking this might have something to do with a template, but it's really weird.

I started off with a .doc file and a .docx file that I had previously edited, combined them, and saved the result as a .docx file. Both files were originally created as templates by someone else long ago.  Within a few minutes, the fonts and spacing of everything in the document have been changed, making a total mess out of my document.  I also noticed something in the lower left corner referencing "contacting" a template.  I never noticed this before with these templates.

What a mess.  How can I make it stop doing this?  If I take the time to reformat everything the way I want it again, I don't want it to revert back the next time my back is turned.

Thanks,

Rebeccah

Comment: Sorry to hear this happened! I've asked that the moderators move this to the Super User site, since I suspect you'll get better help and assistance there. I hope they can provide a good answer!

Comment: Thanks, templatetypedef.  The moderators are free to move this to whatever forum is best.  I did get it figured out and posted it as an answer - hopefully it will help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

Ah.  I got it figured out.  One of the component documents, and the merged document, had a template attached to it that was stored on a server.  The template file on the server doesn't exist any more - someone must have recently deleted it.  The reformatting apparently reflects Word automatically changing the template to normal.dot.

If I catch it in time, before the changes are made, I can save the file *as* a .dot or .dotx (template) file, and then attach that local template file to future documents so they don't have to rely on the template that is no longer on the server.

How I figured this out:

1. Google found an answer to a question about disabling a long wait for a linked file that no longer existed, leading me to File | Options | Advanced | General - uncheck "Update automatic links at open."  That didn't undo the reformatting that had already happened, but may have prevented reformatting of the component document the next time I opened it.
2. The same answer pointed me to the right side of the File page, where various file properties are displayed.  When I click on "Show All Properties", I can see the file name of the Template file, as the eighth property displayed.
3. General googling about Word templates led me to File | Options | Customize Ribbon | Customize the Ribbon, where I checked the previously empty box next to "Developer".  Now, Developer | Document Template allows me to see and change the location of the document template.
4. I opened a previous version of one of the component files (the .doc file), the one that had the template from the server attached to it, and watched Word search for the template.  But it did not reformat it the file.  I saved the file as .dot, as .dotx with compatibility, and as .dotx - just to be sure I had all necessary options available.
5. I opened my reformatted composite file, went to Developer | Document Template, and specified my recently saved .dotx file as the template, made sure that "Automatically update document styles" was checked, and clicked OK.

Voila!  I have my previous formatting back.

Rebeccah